# stop and start IIS server for TFS build Access denied

Tags: windows, iis, tfs, windows-server

[image]I need to stop and start IIS server for TFS build. When do this using .bat file iisreset /stop, similarly for start.

When I do this I get

> Access denied, you must be an administrator of the remote computer to use this command. Either have your account added to the administrator local group of the remote computer or to the domain administrator global group.

Please note: This is Windows server 2019

1. I am already admin of this machine.
2. I have given read/write access to everyone in this folder.
3. I have unset EnableLUA to '0' in the registry as told in [link for site](https://original-network.com/script-to-disable-uac-server-on-windows-server-2019/)
4. Above all these, I restarted machine.

I still get error in TFS build.

Comment: Locally when yo run it it's ok?

Comment: yes, Locally there is no problem

Comment: what account your build agent is running on? If it is a specific functional ID then you may need to add that account to admin group on the box.

Comment: TFS runs as Network Service and for this I have given read/write permission

Comment: Adding "Network Service" account to Administrators group should resolve the issue... however is not an ideal approach., if this resolves you would need to find the policy which restricts user to run files on elevated mode and assign that permission.

Comment: I have unset EnableLUA to '0' in the registry, it was this asking the script to run as administrator, I have unset this variable in registry

Comment: the cx needs to use administrator to manage his agent service to make sure the agent has administrator permission.(image)[https://imgur.com/p9hMSdg]

Comment: after finishing changes, please let cx restart Agent service.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do IISRESET in your batch script. You need to be an Administrator as basic right to execute IISRESET command. So the account which the build is running needs to be part of the Admin group on the box.

Other approach is to stop and start w3svc using sc config commands or NET STOP WAS /Y and NET START W3SVC

Answer (score 1):

When you start a build in TFS the execution of that build is effectively done by a build agent. A build agent is just a service running on any particular machine. So, your batch file that shall start/stop the IIS service will be executed by whatever build agent is running your particular build.

This in terms means that your batch file is executed by the user that is used to run the build service. If that user does not have the necessary admin rights you face this particular error message.

What you need to do is make sure that all accounts that you use to run your build agents have administrative permissions on whatever machine you want to start/stop IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your answers are correct, I added the 'Network Service' of TFS to admin group of machine. Then build was success. Administrative tools>Computer Management> Local Users and Groups>Groups>

Inside Administrators and Users add 'Network Services'. If you don't find 'Network Service' then change location to your computer node and add them.

Comment: Adding Network Service to an Administrator group is not recommended., you would want to use NET or SC commands to restart IIS instead.